# 5.1 surround sound via optical out without receiver

Tags: audio, mac-mini

I have a 2010 Mac mini and I would like to output 5.1 surround sound from it.

The optical audio out is the way to achieve this, but I don't want to have an audio receiver, 5 times bigger then the mini.

I know there is the Logitech Z-5500 and the new [Z906](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/speakers-audio/home-pc-speakers/devices/speaker-system-Z906) that can do direct optical audio-in, but it seems to be the only option.

Is there other speakers with optical-in or small/cheap adapter?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have 5.1/7.1 (multichannel) audio, you can do it via the optical out (mini-toslink), the HDMI or the Mini-Display Port.

On the receiver side, you must have a decoder, able to decode the stream (PCM for 2 channels and DD/AC3/DTS and their variants) and convert it to analogue signal.

I had the same dilemma when I got my ATV2, I wanted something to be able to utilize my optical SPDIF, and to be able to decode Surround sound. After doing some research, there were several solutions:

- Optical->RCA analogue convertors. Stereo only, like [GefenTV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0021QBIBQ). This doesn't do multichannel.
- A small size 5.1 Decoder - you can read the [HD Audio Rush review](http://www.dr-lex.be/hardware/hdar_review.html) here.
- A Logitech Z-5500.
- Full-blown 5.1/7.1 amplifier.

Personally I decided to go with the amplifier and bought a Pioneer 7.1 receiver.