# How do I tell if my Mac supports Mini Toslink?

Tags: headphones, audio

Apparently on many modern macs the 3.5mm headphone audio jack supports Mini [Toslink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK).

How can I tell whether my mac supports it, whether it supports surround sound (4 speaker or better), and whether the microphone input acts as a mini toslink input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not find a direct source to note when Apple started making audio output ports toslink enabled. But to answer your other questions:

- Almost all macs since 2006 do support this, and looking at the product page for each model will tell you exactly.
- If it supports toslink, it supports surround sound
- [According to this KB, the input is also optical as well](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1596).

Answer (score 13):

Do the following:

1. Open "About This Mac"
2. Open "More Info..." (skip this step on macOS Sierra)
3. Open "System Report..."
4. From the left pane choose Hardware > Audio
5. Check if **Optical Digital Audio Output** is present

[image]

Comment: the best answer, because it works without any online SaaSs, and doesn't depend on third party software.

Answer (score 4):

While not specific to mini TOSLINK, Apple lists all their 192kHz-compatible models on their ["Play high sample rate digital audio on Mac computers" article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202730). (The wording makes it sound like some machines supporting 176.4kHz may not be listed, though.)

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) through MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) through MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2014) through iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2014)
- iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, Late 2015)
- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) through iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- Mac mini (Late 2014)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/). You can find the specs for your own Mac by clicking the "This Mac" item in the left-hand pane.

[image]

From a quick look:

- On the audio output side, the 3.5-mm analog/optical combo jack was added in Mac mini models from Early 2006 and in iMac models from the iMac G5.
- On the audio input side, 3.5-mm analog/optical combo jack was added in Mac mini models from Early 2006 and in iMac models from Mid 2006. A line-level microphone or optical digital audio equipment can be connected to this port as described in this [Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1596) (for the Macbook Pro).

Comment: The microphone input appears to be toslink on at least some models - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1596 so your last statement may need amendment.

Comment: @AdamDavis I'm not so sure, it does say "Connect your MacBook Pro to a line-level microphone or optical digital audio equipment". Isn't "line level" an analog audio term? However, the same port is shared for both line-in (digital or analog) or the microphone, so maybe it does need clarification.

Comment: @AdamDavis I've reworded the 2nd bullet with some of the information from the support page you linked to and removed the 3rd. I hope thats ok. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't list a mac model, you can just pop your serial number of the mac into this URL and see if your model has TOSlink or "digital audio equipment" listed in the specifications.

http://support.apple.com/manuals/#

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't list a specific mac because I've got 3 ranging over 5 years.

Comment: I know - I'm not overly hung up on precise questions unless you're looking for a precise answer without asking that way :-) Open questions areoften are better at drawing out the general answer. Did you know about these two gems ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058151/how-does-system-profiler-retrieve-the-full-mac-hardware-identifier